# The "Search Q&A" translation from Transifex is not used

Tags: bug, localization

The new search hint says "Search Q&A". This string is present in Transifex, but the site engine doesn't seem to use it.

Ru.SO:

[Transifex:8301](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/73585182?key=3ffc82bf6b470fcbe0120ed23ec3c811), already translated.

> [image: ru.so]

Pt.SO:

> [image: pt.so]

Jp.SO:

> [image: jp.so]

Comment: Looks like this has just been fixed!